# MySQL query co-author network

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some trouble writing a MySQL query. Perhaps you could help me out.

I need to know how often an author wrote a book/text with another author. I intend to use the data to build a graph showing the co-authors working together.

The result should look like this:

```
AuthorID CoauthorID count
01111    02222      5
02222    03333      1
...
```

As I am relatively unexperienced in MySQL, I have no idea how to accomplish this. My guess is it needs some kind of cross-table/matrix. Another problem comes from the undirected nature from the co-authorships:

```
author1 --- author2
```

is equivalent to:

```
author2 --- author1
```

However I need the quantity of those two authors working together so that the query should sum this up as:

```
author1 --- author2 --- count: 2
```

This is a part of the structure of my database:

```
* = primary key
# = unique

table 'Texts'
-------------
#TextID
*Title
*Year
...

table 'Persons'
---------------
#AuthorID
*Name
*Birth
...

table 'Authorship'
------------------
*AuthorID
*TextID
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

-Andi

Comment: What happens if 3 or more authors collaborate on a text? How does your model account for that?

Comment: Since the PK of the table 'Authorship' consists of AuthorID and TextID I can input more than 2 authors for each text. Is this problematic in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need for this is the authorship table. It records each author:book mapping. You're asking about finding the **count** of the number of texts for a given **group** of authors, thus this query:

```
Select a.authorid,
 b.authorid as coauthorid,
 count(a.textid) as count
From authorship a
Inner join authorship b
On a.textid = b.textid
Where a.authorid < b.authorid
Group by a.authorid,b.authorid
```

You join the table to itself to create the matrix of author pairings. The on condition ensures that the pair worked on the same text. The where condition ensures that duplicates are eliminated and authors aren't paired with themselves; 2-1 is the same as 1-2 so don't count it twice, and don't count 3 as collaborating with 3. The group by clause breaks up the results by author and co-author, so that the count function considers only the texts found for each individual pairing.

Note that this query omits pairings with a collaboration count of zero. For good performance, authorship should haves indexes on both authorID and textID.

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71afa/1/0

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does this take more than 2 author per text into account? 

Suppose text1 was written by author1, author2 and author3, will each author be counted as a co-author with the other ones?

e.g.:

author1 - author2 count: 1

author2 - author3 count: 1

author1 - author3 count: 1